# Minimum bounty is 50 or 100?

Tags: support, bounty

It says [in the FAQ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/faq#bounty) that I can

> Slice off anywhere from +50 to +500 of [my] own hard-earned reputation and attach it to any question as a bounty.

However, when I made my first bounty a few days ago, the minimum bounty I could slice off was 100, not 50. Why's that?

Answer (score 10):

If you have already given an answer of your own to a question, the minimum bounty is 100.  See:

[How does the bounty system work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work)

for a full discussion.

Comment: Thanks Alan. I must have missed that part of the manual!

Comment: See also [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/64826) for the reasoning behind this.